# Routing between VRFs through an outside bridge link

Tags: dell, vrf

**Note - 2022-11-09: We opened a support ticket with Dell and they think it is a software bug. Engineering is supposedly working on it now. This question may become moot, or, they might decide not to fix it and we will need a complete redesign.**

I have two Dell S5232F-ON switches running OS10. Each switch has several VRFs to segment network traffic. I want to be able to route traffic between VRFs through a transparent firewall, running VyOS. The plan is to advertise routes with iBGP, but I haven't gotten that far - I can't get the VRFs on the same switch to talk to each other at all.

[image: Router connection diagram]

Each firewall only has a single 100G connection, so I need to trunk all the traffic. I can ping from `cr00-dmz` to `cr01-outside` (and vice versa), but I can't even get ARP responses between `cr00-dmz` and `cr00-outside`.

`cr00` configuration

```
interface vlan50
 mode L3
 no shutdown
 ip vrf forwarding outside
 ip address x.x.x.204/31
!
interface vlan150
 mode L3
 no shutdown
 ip vrf forwarding dmz
 ip address x.x.x.205/31
!
interface ethernet1/1/5
 description fw01
 no shutdown
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 50,150,152
 flowcontrol receive off
 spanning-tree disable
!
interface ethernet1/1/6
 description fw04
 no shutdown
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 51
 flowcontrol receive off
```

`fw01` configuration:

```
interfaces {
    bridge br50 {
        member {
            interface eth1.50 {
            }
            interface eth1.150 {
            }
        }
    }
    bridge br52 {
        member {
            interface eth1.152 {
            }
            interface eth2.52 {
            }
        }
    }
    ethernet eth1 {
        hw-id 10:70:fd:9e:49:de
        vif 50 {
        }
        vif 150 {
        }
        vif 152 {
        }
    }
    ethernet eth2 {
        hw-id 10:70:fd:9e:49:df
        vif 52 {
        }
    }
    loopback lo {
    }
}
```

I guess it makes sense that `cr00` wouldn't respond to an ARP request for another IP it knows it owns, but I would expect that it should work because it is a separate VRF. Is there some setting I am missing? Is there any other way to connect VRFs through an external link (not route leaking since, 1. the vlans are in the same subnet, and 2. that is internal to the router and wouldn't send the traffic through the firewall)?

---

Routing information for this link:

```
cr00# show ip route vrf dmz x.x.x.204/31

Routing entry for x.x.x.204/31
Known via connected
Distance 0, Metric 0
Last update 15:26:43
Routing descriptors Blocks:
    via x.x.x.205 vlan150

cr00# show ip route vrf outside x.x.x.204/31

Routing entry for x.x.x.204/31
Known via connected
Distance 0, Metric 0
Last update 15:26:53
Routing descriptors Blocks:
    via x.x.x.204 vlan50
cr00#
```

Each VRF is showing the correct route to get to the other side.

---

This is a simplified configuration. We have more VRFs that are connected the same way, but I tried reducing the problem to the minimum setup.

Comment: We need to see your routing

Comment: I don't have any routing set up yet - I need to start by just connecting the two interface together so one side can ping the other side. Each interface has a route by virtue of being "connected". I added this to the question though.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with VRFs? If you're using an external firewall to route between LANs, then the switches don't need to be doing *any* L3 work.

Comment: @Ricky The firewalls are transparent - that is just what they are. Our existing setup has the transparent firewall between our ISP and our routers, but that means we need to filter our DMZ traffic elsewhere (mainly ACLs in the router which are a pain to keep in sync with the firewalls). We want the DMZ traffic to pass through the same firewall as public traffic, so we really need a separate edge router, but that is not in the budget and we are trying to fake it with VRF.

Comment: Do the MAC tables on the switch and firewall match?

Comment: @RonTrunk That seems to be the issue - both VLAN interfaces have the same MAC address. Dell OS10 doesn't seem to offer a way to override that.

Comment: @yakatz I’m not in front of my system to go test this but try running “system /bin/bash” in enable mode, drop to Linux, and do what is here https://www.wikihow.com/Change-MAC-Address-on-Ubuntu. The VLAN interfaces will show up in “ip a s”. Locate the virtual interface by VLAN number and then change its MAC address and see if that works. If it does you can change it permanently with UDEV rules.

Comment: If you get stuck hit me up https://grantcurell.github.io/#questions - I’m curious to see if this works

Comment: @GrantCurell Interesting results - I emailed you. For everyone else, I will post here when there is a resolution or if this is really not doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell engineering told me that, while it seems like it should work, this is not possible in the current firmware and this capability will not be added to the firmware.